# How can I fit a mesh inside a div or vice-versa?

Tags: three.js

How can I add this mesh inside the red div?
https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/4528/

[image]

I don't understand how this works. Someone told me it's not good to add multiple canvas bacause multiple renderers could lag my webste. But, for example, what if if instead of one red div, I had multiple red divs scattered throughout my website and needed to add a mesh inside each one? How can I do this without multiple canvas? I'd appreciate if someone could actually explain to me how this works instead of just fixing the code.

```
var camera, scene, renderer;
var geometry, material, mesh;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10 );
    camera.position.z = 1;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 );
    material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

```
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>

<div id="overlay">

</div>
```

```
body {
      margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
}

#overlay {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this example: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_multiple_elements  You can find the code for it here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_multiple_elements.html

Comment: And another option: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_multiple_elements_text